# grep regex with hyphens and white spaces

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to fetch a line with the following information `-a string1 -b file1.txt -c string3` using grep.

I tried 
`grep -v grep | grep '[b][:space:] *.txt *[c]'`
`grep -v grep | grep '[b] *.txt *[c]'`

string1, string3 and file1 are variables. So I am looking for solutions using wild characters.

But there is nothing returned. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just use: `grep -F -- '-a string1 -b file1.txt -c string3' file`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the question. string1, string3 and file1 are variables. So I am looking for solutions using wild characters.

Comment: You have a couple of misunderstandings of regex syntax: in regex, "`*`" doesn't mean "any string", it means "zero or more of whatever's right before this". To get "any string", you need "zero or more of any character", which is "`.*`". Also, to use a named character class, you need square brackets *inside a square bracket expression* (i.e. two sets of square brackets): "`[[:space:]]`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```
grep -- '-a [^[:blank:]]* -b [^[:blank:]]*.txt -c [^[:blank:]]*' *.txt
```

- `[^[:blank:]]` matches any non-whitespace character.
- `--` separates options and pattern arguments.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you!